# Analog BpmnAutoLayout in activiti 7

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud, activiti, bpmn

Activiti 5 has a class `BpmnAutoLayout` from the package `org.activiti.bpmn`. I am rewriting the project on Activiti 7 and faced the problem that they decided to remove this class from the new version of Activiti (core and cloud).

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually it exists. Check the artifact org.activiti:activiti-bpmn-layout:7.3.0

Comment: add dependecy in your project   :                                                            
                     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
   <artifactId>activiti-bpmn-layout</artifactId>
   <version>7.11.0</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Actually it exists. Check the artifact org.activiti:activiti-bpmn-layout:7.3.0

The moved classes around to different artifacts in newer versions of Activiti